# Is it possible to get the controller, action and routeValues from a URL (based on the Global.asax routes)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, routes

I have a URL. Is it possible to somehow get the controller- and action-name and the routevalues? (which would normally be generated by the .NET MVC framework based on the definition in global.asax)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, check [Haacked routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx).

Comment: I suppose I had better ask - why do you want to know this? making decision based upon the names of controllers/actions/route-values is going to make you code less loosely coupled.

Answer (score 9):

Where and when do you want to get the values?

From within your code you can call:

```
HttpContextBase context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
RouteData rd = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);

if (rd != null) {
    string controllerName = rd.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string actionName = rd.GetRequiredString("action");
}
```

Please note that this only works from within your application's code. There is definitely no way to get this information about *other* sites and applications.

Comment: Me neither, likely changed since 10 year old post.

Comment: As far as I know, this code should work just fine for System.Web.Mvc on ASP.NET 4.x on .NET Framework. But for ASP.NET Core, this answer doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can get current controller name and Action name by adding Application_BeginRequest method inside your Global.asaxcs file.

Here is an example:

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
        RouteData routeData = urlHelper.RouteCollection.GetRouteData(currentContext);

        string url = currentContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        string httpMethod = currentContext.Request.HttpMethod;   
        string action = routeData.Values["action"] as string;
        string controller = routeData.Values["controller"] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(controller) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(action))
        {
           Logger.Log( controller, action, url, httpMethod);
        }
    }
```